# SQL: How to select two input parameters from three tables?

Tags: sql

Okay, this is related to database given on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

I need to find list of Customers,OrderID, ProductID for orders from Spain. 
The table 'Orders' has OrderID and table 'Products' consists of ProductID whereas the table 'OrderDetails' consists of OrderID and ProductID. I use the following code but I get an error message 'Error: 1 ambiguous column: OrderID'

Here is my code

```
SELECT CustomerName, Country, OrderID, ProductID 
FROM Customers, Orders, Products, OrderDetails
WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
AND Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
AND Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID AND Country = 'Spain'
```

Can someone correct any mistake?

Comment: Learn to use proper `join` syntax.  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: 'OrderID' in the SELECT clause could refer to either the Orders or the OrderDetails table. Add a prefix to specify which one you want.

Comment: Adding prefix to OrderID and productID worked perfectly!! Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the alias names like this:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, 
       Customers.Country,    --Specify the correct table in which you have Country column
       Orders.OrderID, 
       Products.ProductID 
FROM Customers 
 inner join Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
 inner join OrderDetails on Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
 inner join Products on Products.ProductID = OrderDetails.ProductID
where Customers.Country = 'Spain'
```

Also try to avoid comma seperated JOINS. A good read: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)